# Unable to eject disk images or drives in High Sierra

Tags: high-sierra, external-disk, eject, sparsebundle, disk-image

I am running a MacBook Pro Early 2015 13" on High Sierra 10.13.5, and keep getting the "X disk cannot be ejected because one or more programs might be using it" message, when apparently there is no program using that disk (not even Dropbox, Preview).

It happens sometimes when I try ejecting  an external thunderbolt Drive, and always when ejecting any .sparseimages 
I only managed to "solve" this issue and be able to eject the disks by going into Terminal and "respringing" Finder:

```
killall Finder
```

However, I find this solution really inconvenient considering how often I use External Drives and disk images.

I would appreciate if anyone knows any other possible cause or solution, or if my solution is better than forcing the disk to eject.

Edit: After checking what processes were running, it seems there are  "cloudd",  "diskimage" and "QuickLookUIService" processes using a video file from the sparsedisk that are preventing me from ejecting the mounted sparseimage.

Thanks

Comment: Usually its Spotlight indexing that causes this.

Comment: Edit your question to contain the application causing the issue http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080615071312194

Answer (score 5):

Often when a drive is plugged in Spotlight begins to index the entire drive.  While this is occurring Spotlight is "using" the drive and therefore can't be ejected.

Try adding a Spotlight exception:

1. System Preferences>Spotlight>Privacy
2. `+`
3. Select your drive
4. `Choose`

Comment: Adding a Spotlight exception did not work for sparseimages. A little more insight: this sparse image is about 5GB and it's located in the Documents folder. I also have iCloud set up for Desktop and Documents folders. Could it be something related to iCloud syncing the sparseimage updates  ?

Comment: @pggm2r4t Yes, but that would be using the file not the mounted disk

Answer (score 1):

You should download the **Mountain** app. It gives you better control over all mounted volumes. It has been able to unmount or mount disks that I seem to have no control over. It's $6 from  the [developer site.](https://appgineers.de). Before spending the money I would read about it at that site to ensure it does all you want.